# WebBrowser.Navigate - 401 Unauthorized - ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser, http-status-code-401

I'm using WebBrowser control in my asp.net application by creating a STA thread and using it in the thread. Everything was working fine till I changed my administrator account for my web application.

Since then I'm getting the error "Navigation is cancelled". So I extended the webbrowser control as specified in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.createsink%28VS.80%29.aspx) and I handled the NavigateError event. I'm getting the status code 401 which is unauthorized.

Also I tried passing the headers to the Navigate method as given [here](http://peter.hahndorf.eu/blog/2006/08/19/BasicAuthenticationInTheWebBrowserControl.aspx). But still no use.

Any ideas?